# Remove Untested with your version of wordpress message

Tags: php, wordpress

I have launched new updated plugin in WordPress plugin store. But, it is still showing the message.

```
Last Updated : 3 months ago
Untested with your version of wordpress
```

What may be the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually because of the "Tested up to" header in your readme.txt file. Check it and make sure it's at the latest stable version of WordPress(make sure to actually test your plugin with version first!).

If it is at the current stable version of WordPress(if you're running a beta or nightly version of WordPress, say `4.5-alpha...`, then it's normal to get that message), then it's probably just a matter of some time before the WordPress plugin repository picks up the change.

Make sure you're looking at the readme.txt file in the `Stable tag` directory. For instance if your "Stable tag" is `trunk`, then look at `/trunk/readme.txt`. If it's a version(say `1.5`), then look at `/tags/1.5/readme.txt`.